# Vue.js 2: return statement returning multiple values in parentheses (watch & computed)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

EDITED: Added more code for context as requested by the community.

I have a Vue.js 2 app that I am now maintaining where there is a computed property.  This computed property has a return statement that is returning several data properties in a comma-separated format, and the entire group is wrapped in parentheses.

I tried looking at both Javascript and Vue.js 2 documentation, and I can't figure out what this is doing.  In Javascript, if you wanted to return multiple values, you would return an array with the values or an object with multiple properties.

Here is the other weird thing.  This "compoundFormProperty" computed property isn't used in the component template!  There is a watcher on this "compoundFormProperty" property.  I searched the entire code base, and "compoundFormProperty" only exists in this one component.  Since it's not used by the component template, I think it is being used to track some internal state (I think it's used to check if the form is valid). The rest of the computed properties have get() and set() calls, so they appear to reference a Vuex store that stores the data.

```
<script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex";

    export default {
        name: "DeliveryAddress",
        components: {},
        props: {
            countries: Array,
            usStates: Array,
            canStates: Array,
            errorsCount: Number,
            isEdit: Boolean,
            selectedAddress: Boolean,
            sameAsBilling: Boolean
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                sameAddress: false,
                saveAddress: false,
                nameEmpty: true,
                nameTouched: false,
                addressEmpty: true,
                addressTouched: false,
                cityEmpty: true,
                cityTouched: false,
                postalTouched: false,
                invalidDeliveryPostal: true,
                invalidBillingPostal: true,
                formTouched: false,
                storedInfo: {},
                cancel: false,
                editInvalid: false,
                saveInProgress: false,
                sameBilling: this.sameAsBilling
            };
        },
        computed: {
            formInvalid: {
                get() {
                    if (this.selectedAddress) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return (
                        this.formTouched === false ||
                        this.nameEmpty ||
                        this.cityEmpty ||
                        this.addressEmpty ||
                        this.invalidDeliveryPostal
                    );
                }
            },
            compoundFormProperty: function() {
                return (
                    this.deliveryName,
                    this.deliveryCity,
                    this.deliveryAddress,
                    this.deliveryState,
                    this.deliveryCountry,
                    this.deliveryPostal,
                    Date.now()
                );
            },
            ...mapState([
                "name",
                "city",
                "address",
                "addressTwo",
                "country",
                "state",
                "postal",
                "cartObj",
                "accountObj"
            ]),
            cartObj: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.cartObj;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setCart", value);
                }
            },
            deliveryName: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.deliveryName;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setDeliveryName", value);
                }
            },
            deliveryAddress: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.deliveryAddress;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setDeliveryAddress", value);
                }
            },
            deliveryAddressTwo: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.deliveryAddressTwo;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setDeliveryAddressTwo", value);
                }
            },
            deliveryCity: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.deliveryCity;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setDeliveryCity", value);
                }
            },
            deliveryState: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.deliveryState;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setDeliveryState", value);
                }
            },
            deliveryCountry: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.deliveryCountry;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setDeliveryCountry", value);
                }
            },
            deliveryPostal: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.deliveryPostal;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setDeliveryPostal", value);
                }
            },
            accountObj: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.accountObj;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setAccount", value);
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            compoundFormProperty() {
                if (this.sameBilling || this.selectedAddress) {
                    this.$emit("change", { errors: false });
                } else if (
                    this.deliveryName &&
                    this.deliveryCity &&
                    this.deliveryAddress &&
                    this.deliveryState &&
                    this.deliveryCountry &&
                    this.invalidDeliveryPostal === false
                ) {
                    this.$emit("change", { errors: false });
                } else if (
                    this.isEdit &&
                    this.deliveryName &&
                    this.deliveryCity &&
                    this.deliveryAddress &&
                    /^[-/\w ]{2,12}$/.test(this.deliveryPostal)
                ) {
                    this.editInvalid = false;
                } else {
                    this.$emit("change", { errors: true });
                    this.editInvalid = true;
                }
            }
            //Other watchers
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: weird, are `deliveryName`, `deliveryCity`, etc. computed too? otherwise they are a no-op, and the return value of that function is simply `Date.now()`. the syntax `(A, B, C)` is equivalent to just `C` plus the side effects of evaluating `A` and `B` before evaluating `C`.

Comment: The code lacks the context for this code. Consider providing the code that consumes compoundFormProperty for clarity.

Comment: @don_aman It doesn't matter if they are computed, that they are reactive is enough for this to not be noop. The side effect is that these properties are marked to be tracked when evaluated

Comment: The only time this makes sense is if all those properties are actually defined through [getter functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (either with the `get` keyword or through an Object.defineProperty with a `get` property), such that accessing `this.deliveryName` etc. actually _runs code_ rather than merely performing a property name lookup. In that case, this return basically "touches every one of the properties" (running whatever administrative code that runs when that happens), and then returns the time at which it accessed all the values.

Comment: @EstusFlask
I added more code, but nothing consume "compoundFormProperty" other than a watcher.

Comment: @Stephen It makes sense and changes the context a bit, I updated the post

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added more code for context.  As you suspected, the other data properties have get() and set() methods that communicate to a Vuex store.

Comment: @don_aman I provided more code for context.  I agree with you that that return statement would just be the last item, Date.now().  EstusFlask looked at my code after I supplied more details and seems to have figured out what the previous developer was doing, which makes more sense.

Comment: @Stephen Explicit get/set aren't necessary for this to work. It would be the same for `data` properties, as Vue 2 sets up get/set pairs internally for reactive properties, so accessing this.deliveryName inside a computed will result in side effect

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for your input!  I'm still learning the ins and outs of Vue, and inheriting this code from someone else is certainly a way to learn fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript functions can't return multiple values. Expressions delimited by comma operators are evaluated to the last one, i.e. `compoundFormProperty` returns `Date.now()`.

It could be a mistake with comma-separated expression being returned instead of an array. But here it looks like a hack to trigger reactivity in computed property.

Due to how [Vue reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) works, `deliveryName`, etc. properties  are marked to be tracked when accessed on `this`. `compoundFormProperty` will run on any changes in instance properties that are accessed inside computed property.

The explicit and not hacky way is to rewrite this as a collection watcher:

```
data() {
  return { compoundFormProperty: null, ... }
},
created() {
  this.$watch(
    ['deliveryName', ...],
    () => {
      this.compoundFormProperty = Date.now()
    },
    { immediate: true }
  );
}
```

The result may be somewhat different depending on the use, a watcher with `immediate` causes `compoundFormProperty` value to be assigned immediately, while computed property is evaluated the first time when it's accessed.

UPD: the combination of `compoundFormProperty` computed property and watcher in original post is a *very* hacky way to write `this.$watch` with array input, likely because a developer wasn't aware of it, or the code derived from Vue 1.x that didn't have specific functionality to shallowly watch collections. `Date.now()` value is efficiently ignored and used to not cache a computed.

Comment: Since you posted your answer, I added more code for context.
 
But, what you written already certainly clarifies a lot, since this computed property was not being used in the template.  I don't know when this developer wrote this code, so it's unclear if this was started in Vue 1.  By the time I inherited the code, the code seems to follow Vue 2 syntax.

I think the original developer wanted to check if any relevant field listed in "compoundFormProperty" was changed, because there is other code to check the "validness" of the entire form.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the goal. Any way, this needs to be handled with a watcher only. Vue borrowed this part from Angular 1, where this was the preferable and actually the only way to do this, because the latter had no computeds.

Comment: As with most corporate software code, this code will be refactored "when there is time."  The code is working as intended, and we have limited manpower, so I don't think I'll touch this part anytime soon.   In any case, thank you for your reply.  I learned about computed and watchers through the official Vue 2 documentation, so I never thought this hack was even possible.